# Graph Clustering Library in Java

Tags: java, graph, cluster-analysis, graph-algorithm

I am searching for a library (or framework or graph db function or example code) to split a undirected **weighted** graph into clusters.

Additional requirement would be that you can configure the numbers of clusters generated.

I already looked at different things:

- JUNG Framework: Seems not to support weighted edges for clustering algorithms.
- Neo4J DB: Provides some algorithms in core java API, but not for clustering.
- JGraphT: No clustering algorithms.
- Igraph: Not available for Java, only Python, C and R

Does anyone know any other graph clustering algorithm implementations accessible for Java?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Gephi](http://gephi.github.io/) is implemented in Java and contains various community detection algorithms (check the available plugins). It is open source and there's an API system allowing you to integrate its classes in your own source code, or the opposite (develop gephi modules).

See also the answers to this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2948/how-to-do-community-detection-in-a-weighted-social-network-graph

Comment: Thanks man! Was able to integrate the Gephi Toolkit and some plugin jars into my app. Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Good for you! What does your app do, if I may ask?

Comment: It analyzes components/microservices and their coupling to each other and tries to suggests better cuts between the microservices

Comment: Have you considered open-sourcing your tool?